# C++ Access violation reading location in linked list

Tags: c++, list

I have lately been trying to solve [this reddit challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3a64hq/20150617_challenge_219_intermediate_todo_list/)(problem's part 2):

> ### Description
>
> Thanks for that list you made me, my thoughts are way more organised!
>   I've got a few problems though that I thought you might be able to help with? >Sometimes I put the wrong information in a list item. Maybe to prevent this I'd be able to modify/update the list item? That's not the only problem though, when there are 50+ items it gets kind of hard to work my way through. Do you think you could maybe add the ability to categorise my items? Obviously, if I have that, I'd also like to be able to view by category!
>   Oh and finally, a few of you were really great and did this last time but is there a way you can somehow make my list retain state so that I don't have to re-type it everytime I turn my computer on again?
>   The newest To-do list should be capable of the following functionality:
>   Modifying an existing list item
>   Be able to give a list item a category. The list item should be able to take an arbitrary amount of categorys
>   View by category - All list items should be able to be sorted and output by category to make it easier to wade through submissions
>   Retain state
>   Thanks!
>
> ### Formal Inputs & Outputs
>
> #### Output description
>
> Any output that is created should be user-friendly. When I'm viewing my to-do list, I should be able to easily discern one list item from another.
>   Examples
>
> (don't take this too literally, do it how you would like to do it)
>   Categorisation
>
> #### Input:
>
> Category Output
>
> Input:
>   Output:
>       ----PROGRAMMING----
>       - A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel
>       - The Scheme Programming Language
>       - Memory in C
>       - Haskell's School of Music
>       - Algorithmic Symphonies from one line of code
>
> ----MUSIC----
>       - Modes in Folk Music
>       - The use of the Melodic Minor Scale
>       - Haskell's School of Music
>       - Algorithmic Symphonies from one line of code
>
> ----MUSIC & PROGRAMMING----
>       - Haskell's School of Music
>       - Algorithmic Symphonies from one line of code

Modifying an item

> updateItem('Create Sine Waves in C', 'Create Sine Waves in Python');
>       //The item has now changed from 'Create Sine Waves in C' to 'Create Sine    Waves in Python'. This should be reflected in the viewList function/method you  have created.

The error I'm having is that I get 'Access violation reading location '. That's because in my `List<std::string>` I realized while debugging that inside any of that list's nodes `data = <Error reading characters of string>`, but before getting out of `ToDoList::addItem()` `data = "Take a shower"`(or whatever data has to be equal to).

I hope I'm explaining my problem correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node* next = nullptr;
    Node();
    Node(T item);
};

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node()
{ }

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(T item) : data(item)
{ }

template<class T>
class List
{
    Node<std::string>* head;
    Node<std::string>* tail;
    int size;

public:
    List();
    ~List();

    void addItem(T item);
    void deleteItem(T item);
    void display() const;
};
template<class T>
List<T>::List() : size(0)
{
    head = new Node<std::string>();
    tail = head;
}

template<class T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    auto* temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;

        temp = head;
    }
}a

template<class T>
void List<T>::addItem(T item)
{
    tail->data = item;
    tail = tail->next = new Node<std::string>;
    size++;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::deleteItem(T item)
{
    auto* temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if (temp->data == item){
            if (temp == head){
                auto* h2 = head->next;
                delete temp;
                temp = 0;
                head = h2;
            }

            else if (temp == tail){
                delete temp;
                temp = 0;
            }

            else{
                temp->data = temp->next->data;
                auto* te = temp->next->next;
                delete temp->next;
                temp->next = 0;
                temp->next = te;
            }

            --size;
            break;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::display() const
{
    auto* temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "- " << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

class Category
{
    std::string name;
    List<std::string> list;

public:
    Category(std::string name);

    void addItemToCategory(std::string item);
    void doneItemInCategory(std::string item);
    void displayCategory() const;

    std::string getName() const;
};

Category::Category(std::string _name) : name(_name)
{ }

void Category::addItemToCategory(std::string item)
{
    list.addItem(item);
}

void Category::doneItemInCategory(std::string item)
{
    list.deleteItem(item);
}

void Category::displayCategory() const
{
    list.display();
}

std::string Category::getName() const
{
    return name; 
}

class ToDoList 
{
    std::vector<Category> categories;

public:
    ToDoList();

    void addItem(std::string item, std::string category);

    void viewList();
};

ToDoList::ToDoList()
{ }

void ToDoList::addItem(std::string item, std::string category)
{
    if (!categories.size()){
        Category newCategory(category);
        newCategory.addItemToCategory(item);

        categories.push_back(newCategory);
    }
    else{
        for (auto& cate : categories){
            if (cate.getName() == category){
                cate.addItemToCategory(item);
                return;
            }
        }

        Category newCategory(category);
        newCategory.addItemToCategory(item);

        categories.push_back(newCategory);
    }
}

void ToDoList::viewList()
{
    for (const auto& cate : categories){
        std::cout << "------" << cate.getName() << "------\n";
        cate.displayCategory();
    }
    std::cout << "\n" <<std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
    ToDoList list;

    list.addItem("Take a shower", "x");
    list.addItem("Go to work", "x");
    list.viewList();

    list.addItem("Buy a new phone", "y");
    list.viewList();

    std::cin.ignore(2);
}
```

Comment: You do know that `std::list` exists for all of this, right?

Comment: Using `std::list`: http://ideone.com/IP5In9

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah I know, but it just makes it really easy. If I don't find a way of solving this problem I will go for std::list. No clue why my code is crashing? Thanks for answering.

Comment: `Yeah I know, but it just makes it really easy`  So is your program to create a linked list, or is it to categorize items?  If it's the latter, the best way is the easiest way -- then you can go on with other aspects of the program at a much faster pace instead of sitting around debugging a linked list.  I wrote that code in ideone without a real compiler sitting on my desk and without debugging a single line of code.  And the best part -- *it worked on the first try*.  Why?  Because I know that `std::list` works properly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I changed it.

  > So is your program to create a linked list, or is it to categorize items? If it's the latter, the best way is the easiest way.

That's true.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Also, another of the problems I'm having is that as in the challenge says: addItem('Create Sine Waves in C', 'Music', 'Programming); //Belongs to 2 categories, 'Programming' and 'Music');
 
It's adding a item to 2 categories, how may I do that? I know that you can have two functions, one that's: addItem(item, category) and addItem(item, category, category) but what if you want to add an item to 4 categories for instance? is there any way of doing this that's not as tedious as doing a function for every case?

Comment: Well, that is where program design comes into play.  It really isn't a C++ issue at that point.  Maybe supply a vector of categories instead of a single category to add to?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so I would have two functions, one to a single category and another with a vector of categories, seems right. Thanks for helping me! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Just one function.  If a vector has 1 element, then it has 1 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read about the [rule of 5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Basically, by defining a destructor for `List` but not declaring any copy/move constructors, you've made it so doing any kind of copy/move with it is dangerous and will put your `List` in an unusable state. Specifically, look at this:

```
if (!categories.size()){
    Category newCategory(category);
    newCategory.addItemToCategory(item);

    categories.push_back(newCategory);
}
```

What happens here? You construct `newCategory`, copy it into `categories`, then destroy it. Since you haven't defined any copy constructors, this is a shallow copy - it simply copies your pointer values over, not doing anything with the memory they point to. What happens when you destroy it? `~Category()` runs, which calls `~List()`, which deletes all of its `Node`s. Now that you've deallocated that memory, the stuff in `categories` points to garbage.

To fix this, you can define copy constructors for `List` which allocate new `Node`s and copy over all the data. Ideally, you'd define move constructors as well, which would allow you to do this safely and without extra memory allocations.